# ISO C replacement for GCC's computed gotos

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, micro-optimization

### Background:

In an interpreter loop (or other finite state machine) there are a couple ways to dispatch operations (or jump state based on the next input). The obvious way in C is with a switch statement in a loop. However, there are issues with performance using switch inside a loop. In the worst case the switch can be coded as a sequence of branches, which happens if the op coding isn't continuous (or the compiler can't deduce it is continuous). Even in the optimistic case that the compiler generates a jump table, there is still a redundant jump back to the dispatcher (I haven't seen a compiler that inlines dispatching when seeing a switch in a loop). Additionally, there is usually a redundant bounds check in the dispatcher.

This issue was confronted by the GCC team by introducing Computed Gotos. Which is a language extension allows the referencing of a label, which can later be jumped to using `goto` on the label pointer. This generates the ideal assembly code: an opcode-indexed jump table with inlined dispatching after every operation.

### Question:

Is there a way, using ISO C, to generate similar assembly code?

### Notes:

The closest I've been able to come is by writing each operation as a function, placing the function pointers in a table, and exploiting tail call optimization to generate jumps instead of calls. The issue with this is obvious: it relies upon optimization that may or may not be present. Without the optimization the generated code would consume the stack and eventually crash the application.

The ideal assembly code I'm trying to generate (GAS .intel_syntax, similar to NASM syntax)

```
.intel_syntax  noprefix

.section .rodata
optable:
  .quad nop
  .quad add
  # more ops here

.section .text
## interpreter loop entry here
nop:
    call  nextinput          # return value = table index in rax
    jmp   [optable + rax]

add:
    # add stuff here
    call  nextinput
    jmp   [optable + rax]
```

Comment: Can't you write something equivalent to `while (1) { state = state(); }` (where `state` is a function pointer)?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are getting at. I'll add some pseudo-assembly to show ideally what I'd like to ave generated.

Comment: As you describe it, the GCC team considered the issue and decided that introducing a language extension was the best solution.  Why then do you suppose that standard C semantics provide an equivalent?  If they did, no extension would have been needed.

Comment: I mean have each state implemented as a function that returns the next state (or alternatively, sets a global variable).  This approach avoids the infinite recursion you're concerned about.

Comment: But this sounds like a case of premature optimization.  Unless you already have a working implementation, and that implementation runs too slowly, *and* you have determined that the branching in the interpreter loop is consuming a significant amount of run time, you're spending your time and effort in the wrong place.

Comment: Good point John, they wouldn't have introduced it otherwise. This is just some personal research, optimization is the point. And I thought that what you meant Oliver, but wasn't sure. It does keep the stack from exploding, I'll try that out to see what's generated.

Comment: What assembly code compilers generate is completely outside of the scope of Standard C. For that matter the GCC extension you're using only happens to generate the code you want, a future version of the compiler could see through what you're doing and optimize your code into a series of comparisons. Finally in many cases a series of comparisons and jumps is faster than a jump table because the former can be predicted by branch prediction and the later cannot. Have you actually measured your code using computed gotos to see if its faster? Or are you just going by what looks better to you?

Comment: Ross: "Finally in many cases a series of comparisons and jumps is faster than a jump table because the former can be predicted by branch prediction and the later cannot." Is not the case here. Prediction cannot help what cannot be predicted. It even makes things worse. Computed gotos were designed specifically for this purpose and it has been adopted by the CPython interpreter.

Comment: No, computed gotos were added to GCC because they are a feature of languages other than C (eg. FORTRAN) and GCC was meant to support many languages. Branch prediction is paramount here, and it turns out this in fact where CPython's use of computed goto's actually gains its advantage. Having the jump through the jump table replicated at the end of every operation greatly improves the processor's ability to predict branches. However, that doesn't necessary apply to your code. Whether it's an improvement for you is something you need to measure.

Comment: I would trust the compiler to do the right thing. Have you tested that it does not generate good code?

Comment: Concerning "Without the optimization the generated code would consume the stack",  Use of `_Noreturn` in your functions _may_ help reduce/eliminate stack consumption.

Comment: chux, I thought that as well. I figured that if the function does not return it doesn't need to save the return address on the stack, but it still does... Perhaps for debugging?

Comment: @chux and ktb: Noreturn attributes and similar things don't change the calling convention.  The function does still expect a return address at `[rsp]`, and any stack args above that.  It doesn't just get the compiler to emit `jmp` instead of `call` with the rest of the calling sequence the same.  A function that always throws an exception instead of returning still wants to know where it was called from, so it still needs there to be a return address.  IDK how you'd achieve `jmp` instead of `call` in C;  even tail-call optimization leaves the parent return address there.

Comment: @peter  This issue is "using ISO C" and that does not define the calling convention nor specify `[rsp]` nor a hosts of other attributes like "still needs there to be a return address".  That is why my comment emphasized _may_ help.  OP's goal is un-attainable in general, just offering ideas that could selectively meet coding goals.

Comment: @chux: Fair point.  I was talking specifically about GNU C's `__attribute__((noreturn))` for an x86 target, since that's what the OP seems to be interested in.  Other C implementations may have a NORETURN attribute which does help achieve the goal.  It might even help on gcc, at least around the call site if the function definition wasn't visible during compilation of the caller.

Comment: @RossRidge: Computed gotos were also present in Dennis Ritchie's 1974 dialect of C, and it would seem likely that some dialects would have continued to support them throughout the years before gcc.

Comment: @supercat It didn't make into K&R C though, and other than presumably Ritchie's early compilers, I don't know of any C compilers that implemented it. GCC's computed gotos are much different (`int *p = label; goto p` vs GCC's `void *p = &&label; goto *p;`) so it doesn't seem to be inspired by that early implementation.

Comment: @RossRidge: I wonder if any such construct existed in B?  Early C was designed to be a successor to B that would be largely compatible with B on platforms that could accommodate the latter, but which could also be used on platforms that couldn't very well support all of B's semantics to run applications which didn't need all of them.  IMHO, the Standard would have been much more useful if it had included more "optional" features, which implementations could support or not provided that properly-written code that needs a feature can be guaranteed to fail compilation if it isn't available.

Comment: @supercat I was curious about that and apparently it did. It's not explicitly stated in the B Reference doc, but it gives `goto rvalue` as the form of goto implying it can be used with more than just a label. https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/bref.html

Comment: @RossRidge: Given that C was an offshoot of B, and given that B had a number of useful features and guarantees that most platforms could be handled more cleanly and efficiently than the code needed to replace them, I think it's unfortunate that today's compiler writers pretend such features never existed, rather than recognizing that C's popularity stems from the fact that implementations which could support such semantics generally did so.  I recognize that saying that a compiler will behave like PDP-11 C at all times would be expensive, but one shouldn't have to jump through hoops...

Comment: ...in C to do things that would have been trivial in B.  Some constructs from B can reasonably be considered deprecated because better constructs exist in C (e.g. `switch()`), but there are some for which the Standard has yet to define a better alternative (e.g. many situations involving aliasing, overflow, indeterminate values, etc.)

Comment: "This generates the ideal assembly code" -> this is a flawed assumption. GCC's actual implementation of computed gotos is not consistent between platforms/versions/optimization levels, and in many cases it generates a hidden `switch` around your scope and the "labels" are just integers, not direct code pointers. This is one reason it tells you not to use the values outside their scope of origin (and yes, it will do this on x86/x64 with optimization enabled, it's not limited to "obscure" targets). The feature is almost entirely syntactic (it optimizes it the same way it would a `switch`).

Comment: I proposed this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43832336/c89-computed-goto-again-how-to, philosophical usefullness of it aside, in a nutshell it provide a way to map C labels to enum enumerants, the enum being used as switch() variable. All this is generated (cpp) in a clean way so that shuffling labels names and order is easy and coherent. This is all ansi-C. This allow the implementation of dispatchers, interpreters, in a compact and efficient way. This can even be extended to support switch() case limits, i.e hide multi switch() in a single computed goto.