# C89 computed goto (again) how to

Tags: c, goto

I need to code an automata, and I bumped into this old need of a computed goto (ala fortran4 :) )

I need to code this in a portable ansi-C.

I want to stay away from the "don't do that", away from longjmp/setjmp, away from embedded ASM(), away from non ansi-C extensions.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Well, the so called "computed goto" exists only as non-portable extensions in C. Perhaps there is a neater way to solve your problem. What is the problem?

Comment: There is no such mechanism in ansi C. Design your state representation properly and use function pointers that accept its address.

Comment: And BTW, if you want ANSI compliance (i.e. C89) your title is misleading.

Comment: `switch` is computed goto.

Comment: I don't know what a 'computed goto' is.  I sounds kinda nasty, and I'm guessing I don't need to know about it?

Comment: Story Teller is right, I made a typo and meant c89, now is it possible to fix the title, I dunno :(

Comment: @Phi, automata have been programmed for a long time without the need of a calculated goto.  Can you post a snippet of code and let's see what are you trying to do? or at least guess it?

Comment: @Luis Colorado, I know, but as Picasso learned a to draw pigeon legs to the perfection to end up making drawing with 2 eyes on the same side of the face. Similarly I learned to code without the need got goto up to a point that got where more practical for what I am doing. For instance this CGOTO things here can be used for alternate returns too (another ftn4x ism) i.e a function set may return an status code that can be dispatched all along the code i=f(); CGOTO(tb,i); etc...

Comment: @Phi, I don't know about Picasso's pigeon legs, but Picasso had it very difficult to paint without any light or paint.  Please, can you post some code and let's see what have you done?  Please, edit your question and put the code there, as it will be better formatted (include four spaces at the left for it to be formatted as code, please)

Comment: @Luis Colorado, basically the 'need for this' is the same as the one used for all the posts about && label and ASM() IP catching and indexed jump table. In my case there are 2 basics need, A state automata, and backtracking code on error, i.e don't want to code a switch() after each function call to dispatch an error code.

Comment: Well, don't post any code.... I'll not spend more time with your question.... Probably you are right and I'm mistaken, but I don't want to lose more time with this discussion.  Thanks for your attention.

Comment: I am sorry if the title is misleading, may be it should be fixed again. My question was not 'how to avoid computed goto' but more 'how to implement a computed goto in a more or less portable way). Now the need for computed is another flamming debate that I'd like to avoid. At first I was interested with &&label and asm() implementation, until I discover it would not be ok on my compiler (none of gcc/clang) so I gave it some reflexion and landed into this snipped (so I did provide code) that seems to do the job, until may be someone tells me this is flawed, or have another  implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Like I said in a comment, despite your plea to not use anything other than goto, standard C has nothing to offer.

Design your state appropriately, and pass a pointer to it to the handler functions for them to modify. That way the handler can setup the next function to call. Something like this:

```
struct state;
typedef void state_func(struct state*);
#define NULL_ACTION_ADDRESS (state_func*)0

struct state {
    state_func    *action;
    int            value1;
    int            value2;
};

#define INIT_STATE { initial_action, -1, -1}

state_func initial_action;
state_func handle_a;
state_func handle_b;

int main(void) {
    struct state s = INIT_STATE;

    while(s.action != NULL_ACTION_ADDRESS) {
        (*s.action)(&s);
    }

    return 0;
}

void initial_action(struct state* ps) {
    ps->action = &handle_a;
}

void handle_a(struct state* ps) {
    ps->action = &handle_b;
}

void handle_b(struct state* ps) {
    ps->action = NULL_ACTION_ADDRESS;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think I got it, I reviewed all the various threads on this topics and I started to agree that that there where no ansi C solutions, yet I found an way to do this that fit my needs. All solution I saw on stackoverflow where based on the idea to 'get' the addr of a label, then stuff it into a table, then index this table and goto, this is both with gcc/clang non ansi extension or the asm extension.

I gave it another try tonite and got this.

In an include file named cgoto.h I have this

```
#ifndef CGOTO_dcl
#define CGOTO_dcl(N) int CGOTO_##N
#define CGOTO_LE(l) l,
#define CGOTO_LG(l) case l:goto l;
#define CGOTO_def(N)                                             \
  if(0){typedef enum {N(CGOTO_LE)} N; CGOTO_##N: switch(CGOTO_##N)\
  {N(CGOTO_LG) default:CGOTO_##N=0;goto CGOTO_##N;}}
#define CGOTO(N,i) CGOTO_##N=i; goto CGOTO_##N;
#endif
```

The usage is like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "cgoto.h"
int f(int x)
{ //...
  CGOTO_dcl(gtb);
  //...
# define gtb(L) L(l0) L(l1) L(l2)
  CGOTO_def(gtb);
  //...

  CGOTO(gtb,x);
  l0: printf("error\n");
  return(0);

  //...

  l1:return(11);
  l2:return(22);
  l3:return(33);
}

int main()
{ printf("f(0)=%d f(1)=%d f(2)=%d,f(3)=%d\n",f(0),f(1),f(2),f(3));
}
```

In this implementation, the cost of jumping is 2 jumps and a switch() that is sequential, then optimisable. So this is reasonably performing compared to function call, a little less performing than &&label solution at the cost of portability.

With this implementation, labels code (semantic actions) are not confined into a switch() so we can implement jump table with shared semantic actions.

The index is assigned to a local goto_table_index, making the function using this re-entrant (multi threadable), though the optimiser can remove altogether this temp assignment.

The 1st Label in a jump table is 'special' (on this implementation) in the sense that it catch index out of bound, the first label is the 'error' label. If your code is bullet proof, i.e there is no way you can get an out of bound index, then the 1st label has not particular semantic.

```
CGOTO_dcl(gtb);
```

Declare the jump table 'gtb' own index as an auto integer so reentrant.

```
  # define gtb(L) L(l0) L(l1) L(l2)
  CGOTO_def(gtb);
```

Define a jump table named gtb, labels can be entered/removed with L(label) so it is pretty convenient, and this is symbolic by nature, i.e the labels are name with a meaning. With #define as a switch() case, labels addition/suppression often mean #define renumbering that is a problem.

The #define can be separated from the CGOTO_def() but it make more sense to keep them together. The CGOTO_def() though got to be placed after the function local declaration as it contain a switch() that is code.

A uniq jump table can be used in multiple place in the function.

```
CGOTO(gtb,x);
...
CGOTO(gtb,y);
```

A label may be entered in multiple jump table

```
# define gtb1(L) L(l0) L(l1) L(l2)
  CGOTO_def(gtb1);
# define gtb2(L) L(l0) L(l4) L(l5)
  CGOTO_def(gtb2);
```

So all in all, this may looks ugly, yet, the jump table definition though 2 line the #define and the CGOTO_def() is manageable and practical, semi performant, and portable.

We are back to FTN4 :)

Cheers,
Phi

Comment: This is some seriously horrible spaghetti code. The need to have a "computed goto" to begin with most likely originated from muddy program design, and all this crazy macro meta programming cannot be a sound solution to any existing problem. The actual solution to your original problem is almost certainly to fix the original program design.

Comment: The being said... since we just threw all good programming practice out the window... I cannot grasp how the setjmp/longjmp functions would be worse.

Comment: This is honestly a very interesting solution. `case l: goto l` gives enough information to the compiler that it might even be able to optimize to a single jump.

Sorry about all the C "elitists"; they can't grasp the reason why someone asks a question like this. I've even had one of them with 100,000+ rep tell me "you can't define functions in headers".